# "datasource not a member of org.apache.phoenix" when trying to Save DataFrames to Phoenix using DataSourceV2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to Save DataFrames to Phoenix using DataSourceV2 following the below mentioned source:

[Apache Spark plugin](http://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html)

I created a dataframe and I want to save it to phoenix in the following way:

```
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    import org.apache.phoenix.spark.datasource.v2.PhoenixDataSource

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark sql to convert rdd to df")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext= new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val MasterDF = MasterRecordSeq.toDF()

    MasterDF.write
      .format("phoenix")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .options(Map("table" -> masterTableName, PhoenixDataSource.ZOOKEEPER_URL -> "phoenix-server:2181"))
      .save()
```

But the `import org.apache.phoenix.spark.datasource.v2.PhoenixDataSource` is not being recognized. It throws the following error:

`object datasource is not a member of package org.apache.phoenix.spark`

I have searched through a lot of internet but I'm not able to find what the bug is.

The following are the dependencies I added in build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-spark" % "5.0.0-HBase-2.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-core" % "5.0.0-HBase-2.0"
```

The following is the complete build file:

```
import NativePackagerHelper._
import java.util.Properties
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.MappingsHelper._
//import sbtrelease.ReleaseStateTransformations._


name := """gavel"""
//scapegoatVersion in ThisBuild := "1.1.0"
//version := sys.env.get("BUILD_NUMBER").getOrElse("3.0-LOCAL")
version := "3.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

//crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.11", "2.12.3")
//scapegoatVersion in ThisBuild := "1.3.5"
scalaBinaryVersion in ThisBuild := "2.12"
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.6", "-target", "1.6")

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-feature")

scalacOptions in (Compile, doc) ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-diagrams", "-implicits", "-skip-packages", "samples")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala,sbtdocker.DockerPlugin,JavaAppPackaging).settings(
  watchSources ++= (baseDirectory.value / "public/frontend" ** "*").get
)

mainClass := Some("play.core.server.ProdServerStart")
fullClasspath in assembly += Attributed.blank(PlayKeys.playPackageAssets.value)

mappings in Universal ++= directory(baseDirectory.value / "public")

unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "libs"

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1",
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "3.0.0",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "3.0.0",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.0",
    "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.0.0" % "test",
    specs2 % Test,
   // "io.rest-assured" % "rest-assured" % "3.0.0" % "test",
   // "io.rest-assured" % "scala-support" % "3.0.0" % "test",
   // "com.squareup.okhttp" % "mockwebserver" % "2.5.0" % "test",
    "javax.mail" % "mail" % "1.4",
     "io.swagger" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.6.1",
     "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.4.0",
     "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.4.0",
     "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "1.7.1",
"commons-io"                 %  "commons-io"             % "2.4",
  "com.typesafe.akka"          %% "akka-actor"             % "2.4.16",
  "com.typesafe.akka"          %% "akka-testkit"           % "2.4.16"           % "test",
  "org.typelevel"              %% "macro-compat"           % "1.1.1",
  "org.scala-lang"             %  "scala-reflect"          % scalaVersion.value % "provided",
  "org.scalatest"              %% "scalatest"              % "3.0.0"            % "test",
  compilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" %% "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full),      

      guice
)
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.101tec" % "zkclient" % "0.4",
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.10" % "0.8.1.1"
    exclude("javax.jms", "jms")
    exclude("com.sun.jdmk", "jmxtools")
    exclude("com.sun.jmx", "jmxri")
)
libraryDependencies += ws
libraryDependencies += ehcache
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-spark
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-spark" % "5.0.0-HBase-2.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.google.protobuf" % "protobuf-java" % "2.4.0"

libraryDependencies  += "org.codehaus.jackson" % "jackson-mapper-asl" % "1.9.13"
libraryDependencies  += "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-queryserver-client" % "4.13.1-HBase-1.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.takezoe" %% "solr-scala-client" % "0.0.19"

libraryDependencies += "com.squareup.okhttp" % "okhttp" % "2.7.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.threeten" % "threetenbp" % "1.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.gsonfire" % "gson-fire" % "1.0.1"

libraryDependencies += "au.com.bytecode" % "opencsv" % "2.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.simplejavamail" % "simple-java-mail" % "5.0.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.solr" % "solr-solrj" % "6.6.2"

libraryDependencies += "com.jcraft" % "jsch" % "0.1.55"

libraryDependencies += "com.vmware" % "vijava" % "5.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "6.1.0.jre8" % Test
//libraryDependencies += "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "sqljdbc4" % "4.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.17"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.17"


libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-core" % "5.0.0-HBase-2.0"



crossSbtVersions := Seq("0.13.17", "1.1.6")

publishTo := {
    val isSnapshotValue = isSnapshot.value
    val nexus = "https://oss.sonatype.org/"
    if(isSnapshotValue) Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
    else Some("releases" at nexus + "service/local/staging/deploy/maven2")
}

publishMavenStyle := true

publishArtifact in Test := false

parallelExecution in Test := false

dockerfile in docker := {
  // The assembly task generates a fat JAR file
  val artifact: File = assembly.value
  val artifactTargetPath = s"/app/${artifact.name}"

  new Dockerfile {
    from("java")
    from("mysql:5.7")
    add(artifact, artifactTargetPath)
    entryPoint("java", "-jar", artifactTargetPath)
  }
}

val appProperties = settingKey[Properties]("The application properties")
appProperties := {
  val prop = new Properties()
  IO.load(prop, new File("./conf/database.conf"))
  prop
}

javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf"

resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
sourceDirectories in (Compile, TwirlKeys.compileTemplates) :=
  (unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile).value

flywayDriver := "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

flywayUrl := appProperties.value.getProperty("slick.dbs.default.db.url").replaceAll("\"", "")
flywayUser := appProperties.value.getProperty("slick.dbs.default.db.user")
flywayPassword := appProperties.value.getProperty("slick.dbs.default.db.password").replaceAll("\"", "")
flywayLocations := Seq("filesystem:conf/db/default")

fork in run := true
//coverageEnabled := false
//coverageMinimum := 70
//coverageFailOnMinimum := true
//coverageHighlighting := true

publishArtifact in Test := false

parallelExecution in Test := false


enablePlugins(SbtProguard)

import com.lightbend.sbt.SbtProguard._
javaOptions in (Proguard, proguard) := Seq("-Xmx2G")

proguardOptions in Proguard ++= Seq("-dontnote", "-dontwarn", "-ignorewarnings")
proguardOptions in Proguard += ProguardOptions.keepMain("some.MainClass")

proguardMergeStrategies in Proguard += ProguardMerge.append("*.conf")

proguardMergeStrategies in Proguard ++= Seq(
  ProguardMerge.discard("\\.zip$".r),
   ProguardMerge.discard("\\.xml$".r),
    ProguardMerge.discard("\\.txt$".r),
     ProguardMerge.discard("\\.conf$".r),
      ProguardMerge.discard("\\.jar$".r)

)
```

My phoenix version is 5.0. My Hbase version is 2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78. Am I missing any configuration?

Comment: your spark versions are different , can you use same versions & try again.

Comment: changed both to 2.4.5 , but the issue isn't resolved yet

Comment: Can you post complete build file if possible ??

Comment: @Srinivas Posted the complete build file.

Comment: also can you post code how are you using phoenix.. if possible

Comment: How I am using it through my code..?

Comment: @Srinivas I posted the code where I am trying to save a data frame to phoenix

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (error), but in my specific case it was for a scala script in a Hortonworks Big Data cluster to be executed by Spark

I managed to solve it by compiling the phoenix-spark repository available on github and importing the jar into the spark directory.

Here are the commands I ran to build the jar, I hope it helps.

```
sudo yum install maven

wget https://github.com/apache/phoenix-connectors/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd phoenix-connectors/phoenix-spark

mvn clean compile
mvn package
cd target/scala-2.12/
cp phoenix-spark-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/jars
```